# Make a custom control or a custom panel receive events in design time in UWP

Tags: events, uwp, design-time

How to make a custom control or a custom panel receive events in design time in UWP?
For example, a custom control could receive an event on resizing and a custom panel an event when another control is pushed inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive an event when the custom control resized, you could subscribe to the `SizeChanged` event. When the size of control changed the `SizeChanged` event will be invoked and then you could handle the new size or previous size from `SizeChangedEventArgs`.

```
<Button SizeChanged="Button_SizeChanged"/>

private void Button_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // do some stuf
}
```

You could  also create `Resize` event to listen to the variety of control size based on `SizeChanged` event.

```
<local:CustomControl Resize="CustomControl_Resize"/>


public sealed class CustomControl : TextBox
{
    public event SizeChangedEventHandler Resize;

    public CustomControl()
    {
        this.SizeChanged += CustomControl_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void CustomControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if(this.Resize != null)
        {
            this.Resize(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

> could recieve an event on resize and a custom panel an event when another control is pushed inside it.

You could invoke your custom event in the [`ArrangeOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/boxpanel-example-custom-panel#arrangeoverride) method. Because the necessary pattern of an ArrangeOverride implementation is the loop through each element in Panel.Children. Always call the Arrange method on each of these elements.

```
public class BoxPanel : StackPanel
{
    public event EventHandler<ElementEventArgs> AddedElement;
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        if (Children.Count > 0)
        {
            UIElement ele = Children.Last<UIElement>();
            if (ele != null && AddedElement != null)
            {
                this.AddedElement(this, new ElementEventArgs(ele));
            }
        }
        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }
}
public class ElementEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private UIElement newElement;
    public UIElement NewElement { get => newElement; set => newElement = value; }

    public ElementEventArgs(UIElement ele)
    {
        this.newElement = ele;
    }
}
```

If you have subscribed to the `AddedElement` event, the `AddedElement` event will be invoked when the new control pushed inside your custom panel.

```
<local:BoxPanel  x:Name="MyBox"  AddedElement="MyBox_AddedElement">
```

Comment: Are these events for design-time?